# headless OrchardCMS - authorization issue with Grapghql

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth, orchardcms, headless, asp.net-authorization

I am new to OrcardCMS. I have been working with it for some days with no issue, but yesterday I got one which I have not been able to solve since then.

I am creating a headless CMS with Graphql and Facebook login. I test my app with Postman and the integrated Graphql interface in the admin panel.

There are two users so far: the admin and me with my Facebook account. I set my FB user account to Author role, which means I can only query the content items which I own. I set up the OIDC server as well so I can authenticate with Postman and also can sign in to the admin panel.

When I set my FB account role to Administrator, I can query all the content items (not just the ones that I created - this is OK). I assume that if I set my role to Author, I should be able to query only my content items. The strange thing is that when I set my role to Author, I get an error: GraphQL.Validation.ValidationError: Authorization is required to access the field. player.

Is it a bug or I did something wrong?